# Would it work to have a pellet furnace with heat pump AC on same duct trunk?

Tags: hvac, ducts, heat

[image]Here is the idea. I would like to have my heat pump trunk tied to my new pellet furnace for effective heating throughout the house in the winter with a fraction of the energy usage. And then close off the pellet furnace in the summer to allow the heat pump to cool the home using the same existing duct work.

For all you renewable folks thinking electricity and heat pumps are the way to go. The reason to do this: Winter = clouds/rain/snow/fog for weeks at a time = solar does not work = heat pump pulling 2kw/hr is not attainable.

Would this kind of setup work? Specifically I am looking at using two manual dampers to switch between the two blowers. Each blower has its own return (I did not include in the drawing)

The pellet furnace is a Traeger GBU-130 (has a blower mounted on the top) the heat pump is a Ducted mini split, outside condenser and indoor ducted blower/evaporator.

Comment: That sounds awesome and welcome to [diy.se]! Please take the [tour]. You'll note that this is a _QUESTION_ and answer board. So far, you've made some statements. Please [edit] this to actually ask us a question, otherwise this will be closed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a question.

Comment: Is there anything keeping you from simply having your A-coil atop your pellet furnace and running it as if it were any other dual fuel setup?

Comment: Added the question in the title to the body.

Comment: You may want to draw a diagram of what you're planning, and add the model numbers of the pellet stove and heat pump. Use the Edit link under your question to add the model numbers, and the Mountain icon to add the drawing.

Comment: It is now a question, but we still don't know if it's the question the OP wants to ask...

Comment: Where is makeup air coming from?  What about the combustion intake vs exhaust for the pellet stove?  There are two different air loops.  

Why not use the heat pump for heating most of the time?

Comment: No need to burn precious electricity for heat. Even the heat pump pulls 900-2500w. Im saving the heat pumps for the summer when AC is needed.

Comment: Supply air from pellet stove will be ducted from the third story down back into the unit. The heat pump return will come from the basement where it will pull the coldest air.

Comment: I do not want a pricy coil to sit on top the pellet stove. A blower motor is how the pellet stove is designed

Comment: Unless the pellets are basically free, you are likely not saving money (or the environment) by burning pellets to create heat. A good heat pump will get you twice as much (or more!) heat out as you put energy in, so even if your electricity cost is relatively high it still may be cost-effective. And while your one little house burning pellets may not seem like much, that's probably less environmentally friendly than the electricity generation, unless it is burning coal. (Natural gas burns relatively clean, wind/solar/hydro/nuke even better).

Comment: But pellets grow on trees and it _feels_ "green"!

Comment: I have 20kw of Solar and 100kwh of lithium battery. And in the winter the sun does not shine. So basically I do NOT have the energy to burn. In no way is this setup "green", the amount of resources put into developing the tech and getting these solutions available to the general population took an incredible amount of energy. Compare that to the most efficient energy storage in the world the humble tree.

Comment: Can someone look at my idea and give me tips on how to make this work?

Comment: Aha! That (solar/battery as primary (only?) electric) is the part we didn't know. That makes a big difference, because now the pellet stove is *not* simply "I don't feel like using the heat pump" but much more "this is like using gas for heat because I don't have enough electric" and just happens to be pellets instead of gas. Very, very different from the usual situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any reason why this manual A-B switch for the ducts would not work. If return air is fed to both the heat pump AC and the pellet stove, then you're basically toggling one HVAC source or the other.

You could put switches on the dampers so the thermostat lines to each HVAC device gets broken, so the device doesn't get turned on when its damper is closed. (You may be able to get dampers with the cutout switch built in.)